# Statistics usage for customer event

Tags: mathematical-statistics

We are preparing one event for our customers and I need to count numbers we need to prepare for this event (I think my question belongs to statistics and it isn't a homework).

Inputs:

- We have 26 ASCII letters (ASCII codes 65-90) from which customers choose. When somebody choose a letter, he doesn't give it back.
- We have 500 playing cards (= 500 customers can compete) with three empty boxes for letters.
- In one draw customer gets one letter per one draw lot
- The winner is somebody who has three particular letters, e.g. "A","L","Q".

Question: How many letters we need to prepare if we have prices for 100 winners?

Comment: do you mean 'prizes' where you say 'prices'?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 1500 letters, so that all 500 can play (i.e. get 3 letters)

The 100 prizes probably doesn't matter because, I think you'll be lucky to get even 1 winner.  Assuming 58 copies of each of the 26 letters (1508 total), the probability of the first drawer winning is 58x3/1508 x 58x2/1507 x 58/1506 or about 0.00034

Depending on whether they remove any of the 3 winner letters the odds go up and down a bit for subsequent players but I don't think they change wildly.  With the above p(win), the probability of no winners at all is (1-p)^500 or about 84%.  The probability of just one is p(1-p)^499*nchoosek(500,1) or about 14%.  The probability of two winners is about 1%.  For 3 winners, 0.07%, and for 4, 0.003%.  The probability of 100 winners is astronomically small.

Alternatively, if after the 500th person, you started again with the 1st, then you'd probably play for months on end, with one winner about every 7th round.  700 rounds of 500 people with 3 letters would be just over 1 million letters.